# Maximum possible sum less than or equal to k in a 2D array using each row

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming

Given : A two dimensional array , values K and M

Problem : Find the maximum possible sum less than or equal K using all the rows (i.e there should be an element form each row) using  exactly M elements.

This is a snippet of a program, I am having trouble implementing the conditions for each row and M.

```
for (int i = 0 ; i<n ; i++)
    for (int s=0; s<M; s++)
        for (int j=K;j>=0;j--)
            if (dp[s][j] && A[i] + j < K)
                dp[s + 1][j + A[i]] = true;
```

EDIT 1: Rows = M , i.e one element from each row has to be selected.

EDIT 2 : Dynamic Programming Solution, Thanks to @6502

```
ill ret(V(ill) col[101],ill prec[][101],ill s,ill row,ill m,ill k)
{
    if(prec[s][row])
    return prec[s][row];
    else
    {
        if(row==m+1)
        return s;
        ill best=-1;
        int j=row;

        for(int i=0;i<col[j].size();i++)
        {
            if(s+col[j][i] <= k)
            {
                ill x = ret (col,prec,s+col[j][i],row+1,m,k);
                if ((best==-1)||(x>best))
                best=x;

            }
        }
        prec[s][row]=best;
        return best;
    }


}
```

Comment: how many rows does the matrix have? what if it has less than M rows? can we satisfy the condition?

Comment: @svs Rows are always equal to M , i. e one element from each row has to be selected

Comment: Any constraint? How large is K and M?

Comment: @PhamTrung 1 ≤ M ≤ 100 1 ≤ K ≤ 10000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem can be solved using dynamic programming by choosing as state the pair `(s, row)` where `s` is the current sum and `row` is the next row we need to include.

The maximal principle is valid because no matter on which choices we made in previous rows the result depends only on the current sum and the current row index.

In code (Python)

```
cache = {}

data = [[2, 3, 4],
        [2, 3, 4],
        [2, 3, 4]]

M = 3
K = 10

def msum(s, row):
    try:
        return cache[s, row]
    except KeyError:
        if row == M:
            return s
        best = None
        for v in data[row]:
            if s+v <= K:
                x = msum(s+v, row+1)
                if best is None or x > best:
                    best = x
        cache[s, row] = best
        return best

print msum(0, 0)
```

The function returns `None` if no solution exists (i.e. if even taking the smallest value from each row we end up exceeding `K`).

Comment: for a 2 d array of values = {  {2,3,4},{2,3,4},{2,3,4} } , K=10,M=3 , the answer should be 10(2+4+4)  whereas your solution gives 8.

Comment: thanks for the heads up , I have ended up solving the solution using a dfs approach , Please have a look at my code and Review it . I have edited the thread and added the code.

Comment: @shubhamr: probably you made some error in the translation because that test case is solved correctly by the algorithm that was in the answer (see edit, I simply added input data and a call).

Comment: Got it , Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

A brute force approach:

```
bool increase(const std::vector<std::vector<int>>& v, std::vector<std::size_t>& it)
{
    for (std::size_t i = 0, size = it.size(); i != size; ++i) {
        const std::size_t index = size - 1 - i;
        ++it[index];
        if (it[index] > v[index].size()) {
            it[index] = 0;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

int sum(const std::vector<std::vector<int>>& v, const std::vector<std::size_t>& it)
{
    int res = 0;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i != it.size(); ++i) {
        res += v[i][it[i]];
    }
    return res;
}

int maximum_sum_less_or_equal_to_K(const std::vector<std::vector<int>>& v, int K)
{
    std::vector<std::size_t> it(v.size());
    int res = K + 1;

    do {
        int current_sum = sum(v, it);
        if (current_sum <= K) {
            if (res == K + 1 || res < current_sum) {
                res = current_sum;
            }
        }
    } while (increase(v, it));
    if (res == K + 1) {
        // Handle no solution
    }
    return res;
}
```

`it` has the current selection of each row.

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved using boolean 2D table. The value of dp[r][s] is set to true, if its possible to generate sum 's' , using exactly 'r' rows (i.e exactly one element from each of the [0 to r-1] rows). Using this dp table, we can compute next state as

```
              dp[r+1][s] |= dp[r][s-A[r+1][c]]  ; 0 < c < N, 0 < s <= K
```

where N is number of columns(0-based indexing). Finally return the value of max index set in M-1 row of dp table

Following is a bottom-up implementation

```
// Assuming input matrix is M*N
int maxSum() {
    memset(dp, false, sizeof(dp));

    //Initialise base row
    for (int c = 0; c < N; ++c)
        dp[0][A[0][c]] = true;

    for ( int r = 1; r < M; ++r ) {
        for ( int c = 0; c < N; ++c) {
            // For each A[r][c], check for all possible values of sum upto K
            for (int sum = 0; sum <= K; ++sum) {
                if ( sum-A[r][c] >= 0 && dp[r-1][sum-A[r][c]] )
                    dp[r][sum] = true;
            }
        }
    }

    // Return max possible value <= K
    for (int sum = K; sum >= 0; --sum) {
        if ( dp[M-1][sum] )
            return sum;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Note that dp table values for current row depend only on previous row, as such space optimization trick can be used to solve it using 1-D table